# How do you change the height of items or nodes in vuetify's v-treeview?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have tried the code below in a custom css and it has not worked

```
.v-treeview-node__root {
      max-height: 30px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there isn't an easy way for styling the whole node (see this [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7177) on Github) ***but*** you can add a style on a node's label by using [the `label` slot of `<v-treeview>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#api).

Something like this:

```html
<v-treeview :items="items" dense>

  <!-- use the `label` slot of `v-treeview` -->
  <template v-slot:label="{ item }">
    <div class="treeview-item">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </template>

</v-treeview>
```

```css
.treeview-item {
  max-height: 30px;
}
```

Here's a working demo on [codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-roentgen-1ge41?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:45-142)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to reduce the space in between the red borders in your demo

Comment: You can try to add `dense` property to your treeview.

Comment: Other than that, I'm don't think we can manually reduce the height of each node. It may be possible by targeting the vuetify-generated classes but that looks kinda dirty so I won't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :
In your data , you create an object that contains the style you want for your HTML or Vuetify components and then you write your CSS just like you write it normally.
Note: Use "," instead of ";" after each CSS property
Note 2: Use camel case instead of hyphens.For example: use `borderTop` instead of `border-top`

```
export default {
name: 'myComponent',
data(): {
    return {
       styles: {
         maxHeight: 30px
}
}
}
```

Then in the the v-treeview code you add this :

```
<v-treeview :style="styles"></v-treeview>
```

Comment: I have tried. It doesn't work. I am targeting each of the nodes not the entire component

Comment: Add the v-for to target each of the nodes like this : ``` <v-treeview v-for=" n in nodes " :style="styles" > </v-treeview>

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to do that is to use SASS variables, as described in [official docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/). You just have to create a file named variables.scss and put the next lines into it:

```
$treeview-node-height: 30px;
```

Then applies some magic and the nodes in v-treeview are 30px height.
Of course [vue-cli-plugin-vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify) should be installed.

Comment: Note: SASS/SCSS variables are only supported using when using the vuetify-loader. This is done automatically when using the vue-cli-plugin-vuetify plugin.

Answer (score 0):

So close. min-height was blocking you.

```
.v-treeview-node__root {
  min-height: 0px;
  max-height: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an id to your tree view, then use a deep selector

```
<v-treeview id="yourTreeView" :items="items" dense>
</v-treeview>
```

```
#yourTreeView >>> .v-treeview-node__root {
    max-height: 25px;
    min-height: 0px;
}
```